How to index into second level of data structure
I'm new to julia, and have run across this problem a few times. I often want to do something like data[:][n] to get the nth index of every item of data. Sometimes I can find a hacky way around it, like [vv...;;][3,:] for a vector of vectors, or [plt.series_list[i][:label] = newlabels[i] for i in eachindex(newlabels)], but sometimes I just give up and restructure the data I'm working with.
Is there an easier way to interact with slices of the data underneath the top layer?

If the array is a vector of vectors, there is broadcasting getindex:
julia> a = [[1,2,3], [10,20,30], [100,200,300]]
3-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
[1, 2, 3]
[10, 20, 30]
[100, 200, 300]

julia> getindex.(a, 3)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
   3
  30
 300

If the array is a 2D array (a Matrix), you can index with the `:` wildcard:

julia> b = [1 2 3; 10 20 30; 100 200 300]
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
   1    2    3
  10   20   30
 100  200  300

julia> b[:, 3]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
   3
  30
 300


that getindex call was exactly what I was looking for, thanks. using the example from the question, getindex.(plt,:label) is much nicer

Using the getindex method of Bill's answer, you can index arbitrarily far down into a nested vector. You could, for example, define a series with \uparrow, \Uuparrow, \UUparrow, like so:
↑(x,y) = getindex.(x,y)
⤊(x,y) = broadcast((x,y)->broadcast(↑,x,y),x,y)
⟰(x,y) = broadcast((x,y)->broadcast(⤊,x,y),x,y)

this works exactly like you'd expect:
julia> nest=[[[[a+b+c+d for a in [0,1]] for b in [0,2]] for c in [0,4]] for d in [0,8]]
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Int64}}}}:
 [[[0, 1], [2, 3]], [[4, 5], [6, 7]]]
 [[[8, 9], [10, 11]], [[12, 13], [14, 15]]]

julia> nest[2]
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Int64}}}:
 [[8, 9], [10, 11]]
 [[12, 13], [14, 15]]

julia> nest↑2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Int64}}}:
 [[4, 5], [6, 7]]
 [[12, 13], [14, 15]]

julia> nest.↑2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Int64}}}:
 [[2, 3], [6, 7]]
 [[10, 11], [14, 15]]

julia> nest⤊2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Int64}}}:
 [[1, 3], [5, 7]]
 [[9, 11], [13, 15]]


or, taking this to the absolute limit:
julia> nest = [[[[[[[Meta.parse(("\$(0b"*g*f*e*d*c*b*a*")")[2:end]) for a in z] for b in z] for c in z] for d in z] for e in z] for f in z] for g in z]
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}}:
 [[[[[[0x00, 0x01], [0x02, 0x03]], [[0x04, 0x05], [0x06, 0x07]]], [[[0x08, 0x09], [0x0a, 0x0b]], [[0x0c, 0x0d], [0x0e, 0x0f]]]], [[[[0x10, 0x11], [0x12, 0x13]], [[0x14, 0x15], [0x16, 0x17]]], [[[0x18, 0x19], [0x1a, 0x1b]], [[0x1c, 0x1d], [0x1e, 0x1f]]]]], [[[[[0x20, 0x21], [0x22, 0x23]], [[0x24, 0x25], [0x26, 0x27]]], [[[0x28, 0x29], [0x2a, 0x2b]], [[0x2c, 0x2d], [0x2e, 0x2f]]]], [[[[0x30, 0x31], [0x32, 0x33]], [[0x34, 0x35], [0x36, 0x37]]], [[[0x38, 0x39], [0x3a, 0x3b]], [[0x3c, 0x3d], [0x3e, 0x3f]]]]]]
 [[[[[[0x40, 0x41], [0x42, 0x43]], [[0x44, 0x45], [0x46, 0x47]]], [[[0x48, 0x49], [0x4a, 0x4b]], [[0x4c, 0x4d], [0x4e, 0x4f]]]], [[[[0x50, 0x51], [0x52, 0x53]], [[0x54, 0x55], [0x56, 0x57]]], [[[0x58, 0x59], [0x5a, 0x5b]], [[0x5c, 0x5d], [0x5e, 0x5f]]]]], [[[[[0x60, 0x61], [0x62, 0x63]], [[0x64, 0x65], [0x66, 0x67]]], [[[0x68, 0x69], [0x6a, 0x6b]], [[0x6c, 0x6d], [0x6e, 0x6f]]]], [[[[0x70, 0x71], [0x72, 0x73]], [[0x74, 0x75], [0x76, 0x77]]], [[[0x78, 0x79], [0x7a, 0x7b]], [[0x7c, 0x7d], [0x7e, 0x7f]]]]]]

julia> nest[2]
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}:
 [[[[[0x40, 0x41], [0x42, 0x43]], [[0x44, 0x45], [0x46, 0x47]]], [[[0x48, 0x49], [0x4a, 0x4b]], [[0x4c, 0x4d], [0x4e, 0x4f]]]], [[[[0x50, 0x51], [0x52, 0x53]], [[0x54, 0x55], [0x56, 0x57]]], [[[0x58, 0x59], [0x5a, 0x5b]], [[0x5c, 0x5d], [0x5e, 0x5f]]]]]
 [[[[[0x60, 0x61], [0x62, 0x63]], [[0x64, 0x65], [0x66, 0x67]]], [[[0x68, 0x69], [0x6a, 0x6b]], [[0x6c, 0x6d], [0x6e, 0x6f]]]], [[[[0x70, 0x71], [0x72, 0x73]], [[0x74, 0x75], [0x76, 0x77]]], [[[0x78, 0x79], [0x7a, 0x7b]], [[0x7c, 0x7d], [0x7e, 0x7f]]]]]

julia> nest↑2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}:
 [[[[[0x20, 0x21], [0x22, 0x23]], [[0x24, 0x25], [0x26, 0x27]]], [[[0x28, 0x29], [0x2a, 0x2b]], [[0x2c, 0x2d], [0x2e, 0x2f]]]], [[[[0x30, 0x31], [0x32, 0x33]], [[0x34, 0x35], [0x36, 0x37]]], [[[0x38, 0x39], [0x3a, 0x3b]], [[0x3c, 0x3d], [0x3e, 0x3f]]]]]
 [[[[[0x60, 0x61], [0x62, 0x63]], [[0x64, 0x65], [0x66, 0x67]]], [[[0x68, 0x69], [0x6a, 0x6b]], [[0x6c, 0x6d], [0x6e, 0x6f]]]], [[[[0x70, 0x71], [0x72, 0x73]], [[0x74, 0x75], [0x76, 0x77]]], [[[0x78, 0x79], [0x7a, 0x7b]], [[0x7c, 0x7d], [0x7e, 0x7f]]]]]

julia> nest.↑2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}:
 [[[[[0x10, 0x11], [0x12, 0x13]], [[0x14, 0x15], [0x16, 0x17]]], [[[0x18, 0x19], [0x1a, 0x1b]], [[0x1c, 0x1d], [0x1e, 0x1f]]]], [[[[0x30, 0x31], [0x32, 0x33]], [[0x34, 0x35], [0x36, 0x37]]], [[[0x38, 0x39], [0x3a, 0x3b]], [[0x3c, 0x3d], [0x3e, 0x3f]]]]]
 [[[[[0x50, 0x51], [0x52, 0x53]], [[0x54, 0x55], [0x56, 0x57]]], [[[0x58, 0x59], [0x5a, 0x5b]], [[0x5c, 0x5d], [0x5e, 0x5f]]]], [[[[0x70, 0x71], [0x72, 0x73]], [[0x74, 0x75], [0x76, 0x77]]], [[[0x78, 0x79], [0x7a, 0x7b]], [[0x7c, 0x7d], [0x7e, 0x7f]]]]]

julia> nest⤊2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}:
 [[[[[0x08, 0x09], [0x0a, 0x0b]], [[0x0c, 0x0d], [0x0e, 0x0f]]], [[[0x18, 0x19], [0x1a, 0x1b]], [[0x1c, 0x1d], [0x1e, 0x1f]]]], [[[[0x28, 0x29], [0x2a, 0x2b]], [[0x2c, 0x2d], [0x2e, 0x2f]]], [[[0x38, 0x39], [0x3a, 0x3b]], [[0x3c, 0x3d], [0x3e, 0x3f]]]]]
 [[[[[0x48, 0x49], [0x4a, 0x4b]], [[0x4c, 0x4d], [0x4e, 0x4f]]], [[[0x58, 0x59], [0x5a, 0x5b]], [[0x5c, 0x5d], [0x5e, 0x5f]]]], [[[[0x68, 0x69], [0x6a, 0x6b]], [[0x6c, 0x6d], [0x6e, 0x6f]]], [[[0x78, 0x79], [0x7a, 0x7b]], [[0x7c, 0x7d], [0x7e, 0x7f]]]]]

julia> nest.⤊2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}:
 [[[[[0x04, 0x05], [0x06, 0x07]], [[0x0c, 0x0d], [0x0e, 0x0f]]], [[[0x14, 0x15], [0x16, 0x17]], [[0x1c, 0x1d], [0x1e, 0x1f]]]], [[[[0x24, 0x25], [0x26, 0x27]], [[0x2c, 0x2d], [0x2e, 0x2f]]], [[[0x34, 0x35], [0x36, 0x37]], [[0x3c, 0x3d], [0x3e, 0x3f]]]]]
 [[[[[0x44, 0x45], [0x46, 0x47]], [[0x4c, 0x4d], [0x4e, 0x4f]]], [[[0x54, 0x55], [0x56, 0x57]], [[0x5c, 0x5d], [0x5e, 0x5f]]]], [[[[0x64, 0x65], [0x66, 0x67]], [[0x6c, 0x6d], [0x6e, 0x6f]]], [[[0x74, 0x75], [0x76, 0x77]], [[0x7c, 0x7d], [0x7e, 0x7f]]]]]

julia> nest⟰2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}:
 [[[[[0x02, 0x03], [0x06, 0x07]], [[0x0a, 0x0b], [0x0e, 0x0f]]], [[[0x12, 0x13], [0x16, 0x17]], [[0x1a, 0x1b], [0x1e, 0x1f]]]], [[[[0x22, 0x23], [0x26, 0x27]], [[0x2a, 0x2b], [0x2e, 0x2f]]], [[[0x32, 0x33], [0x36, 0x37]], [[0x3a, 0x3b], [0x3e, 0x3f]]]]]
 [[[[[0x42, 0x43], [0x46, 0x47]], [[0x4a, 0x4b], [0x4e, 0x4f]]], [[[0x52, 0x53], [0x56, 0x57]], [[0x5a, 0x5b], [0x5e, 0x5f]]]], [[[[0x62, 0x63], [0x66, 0x67]], [[0x6a, 0x6b], [0x6e, 0x6f]]], [[[0x72, 0x73], [0x76, 0x77]], [[0x7a, 0x7b], [0x7e, 0x7f]]]]]

julia> nest.⟰2
2-element Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{Vector{UInt8}}}}}}:
 [[[[[0x01, 0x03], [0x05, 0x07]], [[0x09, 0x0b], [0x0d, 0x0f]]], [[[0x11, 0x13], [0x15, 0x17]], [[0x19, 0x1b], [0x1d, 0x1f]]]], [[[[0x21, 0x23], [0x25, 0x27]], [[0x29, 0x2b], [0x2d, 0x2f]]], [[[0x31, 0x33], [0x35, 0x37]], [[0x39, 0x3b], [0x3d, 0x3f]]]]]
 [[[[[0x41, 0x43], [0x45, 0x47]], [[0x49, 0x4b], [0x4d, 0x4f]]], [[[0x51, 0x53], [0x55, 0x57]], [[0x59, 0x5b], [0x5d, 0x5f]]]], [[[[0x61, 0x63], [0x65, 0x67]], [[0x69, 0x6b], [0x6d, 0x6f]]], [[[0x71, 0x73], [0x75, 0x77]], [[0x79, 0x7b], [0x7d, 0x7f]]]]]

Sadly, prec-power evaluates in the wrong direction to chain them in this direction, but if you're fine being careful with your multiplications prec-times does the correct order.

yes, I am aware comprehensions can make n-dimensional arrays, I'm just putting an example here
